# Why is spark throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException expection for empty attributes?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Context**

I am using **Spark 1.5**.

I have a file *records.txt* which is `ctrl A` delimited and in that file 31st index is for subscriber_id. For some records the subscriber_id is empty. Record with subscriber_id is NOT empty.

Here subscriber_id(`UK8jikahasjp23`) is located at one before the last attribute:

```
99^A2013-12-11^A23421421412^qweqweqw2222^A34232432432^A365633049^A1^A6yudgfdhaf9923^AAC^APrimary DTV^AKKKR DATA+ PVR3^AGrundig^AKKKR PVR3^AKKKR DATA+ PVR3^A127b146^APVR3^AYes^ANo^ANo^ANo^AYes^AYes^ANo^A2017-08-07 21:27:30.000000^AYes^ANo^ANo^A6yudgfdhaf9923^A7290921396551747605^A2013-12-11 16:00:03.000000^A7022497306379992936^AUK8jikahasjp23^A
```

Record with subscriber_id is empty:

```
23^A2013-12-11^A23421421412^qweqweqw2222^A34232432432^A365633049^A1^A6yudgfdhaf9923^AAC^APrimary DTV^AKKKR DATA+ PVR3^AGrundig^AKKKR PVR3^AKKKR DATA+ PVR3^A127b146^APVR3^AYes^ANo^ANo^ANo^AYes^AYes^ANo^A2017-08-07 21:27:30.000000^AYes^ANo^ANo^A6yudgfdhaf9923^A7290921396551747605^A2013-12-11 16:00:03.000000^A7022497306379992936^A^A
```

**Problem**

I am getting **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** for the records with empty subscriber_id.

Why is spark throwing  **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** for the empty values for the field subscriber_id?

> > 16/08/20 10:22:18 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 31.0 in stage 8.0  : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 31

```
 case class CustomerCard(accountNumber:String, subscriber_id:String,subscriptionStatus:String )

     object CustomerCardProcess {
    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)


   def doPerform(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: HiveContext, custCardRDD: RDD[String]): DataFrame = {

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    log.info("doCustomerCardProcess method started")
     val splitRDD        =    custCardRDD.map(elem => elem.split("\\u0001"))
     val schemaRDD       =    splitRDD.map(arr => new CustomerCard( arr(3).trim, arr(31).trim,arr(8).trim))

schemaRDD.toDF().registerTempTable("customer_card")
val custCardDF = sqlContext.sql(
  """
    |SELECT
    |accountNumber,
    |subscriber_id
    |FROM
    |customer_card
    |WHERE
    |subscriptionStatus IN('AB', 'AC', 'PC')
    |AND accountNumber IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(accountNumber) > 0
  """.stripMargin)

log.info("doCustomerCardProcess method ended")
custCardDF
  }

}
```

**Error**

> 13/09/12 23:22:18 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 31.0 in
>   stage 8.0 (TID 595, : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 31 at
>   com.org.CustomerCardProcess$$anonfun$2.apply(CustomerCardProcess.scala:23)
>   at
>   com.org.CustomerCardProcess$$anonfun$2.apply(CustomerCardProcess.scala:23)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389) at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327) at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327) at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.insertAll(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:73)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Could anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `split` function is neglecting all the empty fields at the end of splitted line. So,

Change your following line

```
 val splitRDD = custCardRDD.map(elem => elem.split("\\u0001"))
```

to

```
val splitRDD = custCardRDD.map(elem => elem.split("\\u0001", -1))
```

`-1` tells to consider all the empty fields.

Comment: Great answer, Does it applicable for other delimiters such as  comma, pipe or Is it applicable for ctrl A only ?

Comment: this is applicable for all the delimiter that you use in split function. its a parameter to split function. :) thanks for the acceptance and upvote

Comment: Hi Ramesh I see that split function is neglecting all the empty fields only if that field is located at last position of the line that we split . If there are empty fields at 3rd pos or 8th pos then  split function works fine . Is my understanding correct?

Comment: until you have values until the end of the line, all empty fields will be considered. but if you have all empty fields until the end of the line then all the empty fields will be discarded. And -1 tells to include those. I hope i am clear :)

Comment: Yes. That means lets say if 31st pos is empty and 32nd pos is having valid value then I don't have to apply -1 . Is that correct ?

Comment: Perfect . Thanks Much

Comment: my pleasure @SurenderRaja